# Python-selecting specified items from dictionary list

Tags: python

Let's say I have list of cars:

```
car=[{'model':'ferrari', 'color': 'red', 'price':1200},
{'model':'lamborgini', 'color': 'blue', 'price':2000},
{'model':'ferrari', 'color': 'yellow', 'price':1000},
{'model':'ferrari', 'color': 'yellow', 'price':500}]
```

I want to select the cheapest car for every model-color combination(cheapest red lamborgini, cheapest green ferrari etc) and put them in new list.

The output should be:

```
[{'model':'ferrari', 'color': 'red', 'price':1200},
{'model':'lamborgini', 'color': 'blue', 'price':2000},
{'model':'ferrari', 'color': 'yellow', 'price':500}]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question a little bit more. Maybe add an example. I don't see why 'red'+'lamborgini' should be the cheapest. The color green is nowhere in your list

Comment: @Miguellissimo Look at the edit or my answer

Answer (score 1):

It may be a good idea to create a helper datastructure.
Here I use a dictionary with tuples of (model, color) as keys

```
>>> car = [ {'model':'ferrari', 'color': 'red', 'price':1200},
... {'model':'lamborgini', 'color': 'blue', 'price':2000},
... {'model':'ferrari', 'color': 'yellow', 'price':1000},
... {'model':'ferrari', 'color': 'yellow', 'price':500} ]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> D = defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in car:
...     D[item['model'], item['color']].append(item)
... 
>>> min(D['ferrari', 'yellow'], key=itemgetter('price'))
{'color': 'yellow', 'model': 'ferrari', 'price': 500}
```

This means you don't need to scan the entire collection every time you make a query

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
car = [ {'model':'ferrari', 'color': 'red', 'price':1200},
{'model':'lamborgini', 'color': 'blue', 'price':2000},
{'model':'ferrari', 'color': 'yellow', 'price':1000},
{'model':'ferrari', 'color': 'yellow', 'price':500} ]

newcar = []

for c in car:
    new = True
    for n in newcar:
        if c['model']==n['model']:
            if c['color']==n['color']:
                if c['price'] < n['price']:
                    n['price'] = c['price']
                    new = False
    if new:
        newcar.append(c)
```

And the `newcar` variable will store the cheapest. I tested this with your case and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

sort and filter:

```
 # keep models together and sort by lowest price
srt = sorted(cars, key=lambda x: (x["model"], x["price"]))

# add cheapest of first model in the list
final = [srt[0]]

for d in srt[1:]:
    if final[-1]["color"] != d["color"]:
        final.append(d)
print final
[{'color': 'yellow', 'model': 'ferrari', 'price': 500}, {'color': 'red', 'model': 'ferrari', 'price': 1200}, {'color': 'blue', 'model': 'lamborgini', 'price': 2000}]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cars = [ {'model':'ferrari', 'color': 'red', 'price':1200},
         {'model':'lamborgini', 'color': 'blue', 'price':2000},
         {'model':'ferrari', 'color': 'yellow', 'price':1000},
         {'model':'ferrari', 'color': 'yellow', 'price':500} ]
uniques = {}
for car in cars:
    if car['model'] not in uniques:
        uniques[car['model']] = {}
    if car['color'] not in uniques[car['model']]:
        uniques[car['model']][car['color']] = float('inf')
    if car['price'] < uniques[car['model']][car['color']]:
        uniques[car['model']][car['color']] = car['price']
print(uniques)
```

Output:

```
{'ferrari': {'yellow': 500, 'red': 1200}, 'lamborgini': {'blue': 2000}}
```